# Weak L_1-convergence of squares 

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f_k$ be a sequence of *non-negative* functions from $L_2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set. Assume that $f_k\to f$ weakly in $L_2$ and strongly in $L_p$, $\forall p<2$. Assume also that $f_k^2\to F$ weakly in $L_1$. Does it imply that $F=f^2$?

Comment: No, thanks, but non-negativity seems to be important. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "yes", even for non non-negative $f_n$.  First assume $f=0$. Since $f_n\to 0$ in $L_1$, WLOG by passing to a subsequence $f_n\to 0$ a.e. and hence $f_n^2\to 0$ a.e. But $f_n^2$ converges weakly in $L_1$ hence is uniformly integrable, whence $\|f_n^2\|_1 \to 0$.

The general case follows from the special case once you verify that $(f-f_n)^2$ is weakly convergent in $L_1$. Since $f_n^2$ converges weakly in $L_1$, it is enough to show that $f_n f$ converges weakly in $L_1$ to $f^2$, which in turn follows from the facts that $f_n$ converges weakly in $L_2$ to $f$ and $fg$ is in $L_2$ for every $g$ in $L_\infty$

Unfamiliar background can be found in standard text books; in particular, the book of Albiac and Kalton.

Comment: The unnecessary assumption that $f_n \ge 0$ makes the problem harder.

Comment: I fixed the final equation in the first paragraph (from $f_n$ to $f_n^2$).

Comment: In the first sentence, do you really mean "even for non negative?"

Comment: Sorry for the unnecessary assumptions